# how to upload file to dropbox via Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, oauth, dropbox, indy-9

I try to upload file into dropbox.
I use dropbox api https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-POST

```
procedure TDropbox.Upload2;
const
  URL = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/';
var
  Response: String;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  https: TIdHTTP;
  SslIoHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin
  https := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create();
  try
    SslIoHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(https);
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;

    https.IOHandler := SslIoHandler;

    Params.AddFormField('oauth_signature_method', 'PLAINTEXT');
    Params.AddFormField('oauth_consumer_key', FAppKey);
    Params.AddFormField('oauth_token', FOAuth.AccessToken);
    Params.AddFormField('oauth_signature', FAppSecret + '&' + FOAuth.AccessTokenSecret);

    Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\test.txt', 'application/octet-stream');

    https.Post(URL + 'test.txt', Params);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(https);
    FreeAndNil(Params);
  end;
end;
```

I got "400 Bad request".
All tokens are correct (other api works well).
How pass parameters for this api?

Comment: "Since the entire POST body will be treated as the file, any parameters must be passed as part of the request URL. The request URL should be signed just as you would sign any other OAuth request URL." - maybe, this is the issue?

Comment: maybe. I know how to pass parameters, but how put file into request body?        `https.Post(URL + 'test.txt?oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key='+     FAppKey+'&oauth_token='+FOAuth.AccessToken+'oauth_signature='+FAppSecret + '&' + FOAuth.AccessTokenSecret, Params);` - 400 Bad request

Comment: Try with this URL, and put file as you did before - via Params.AddFile.

Comment: Just a note: "We recommend you use /files_put instead due to its simpler interface."

Comment: To put the file by itself in the POST body, you simply pass the file to `TIdHTTP.Post()` directly, do not use `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` at all. `TIdHTTP` has several overloaded versions of the `Post()` method. One accepts a filename string as input. Another accepts a non-Multipart `TStream` as input, such as a `TFileStream`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
procedure TDropbox.Upload(const AFileName: String);
const
  API_URL = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/';
var
  URL: String;
  https: TIdHTTP;
  SslIoHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin
  URL := API_URL+ExtractFileName(AFileName)
    + '?oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=' + FAppKey
    + '&oauth_token=' + FOAuth.AccessToken
    + '&oauth_signature=' + FAppSecret + '%26' + FOAuth.AccessTokenSecret;

  https := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SslIoHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(https);
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;

    https.IOHandler := SslIoHandler;
    https.Post(URL, AFileName);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(https);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `%26` instead `&` in `oauth_signature` parameter. There is two values in one parameter concated by `&` symbol.
2. Pass file via `TMemoryStream`.

   ```
   procedure TDropbox.Upload(const AFileName: String);
   const
     API_URL = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/';
   var
     URL: String;
     Stream: TMemoryStream;
     ShortFileName: String;
     https: TIdHTTP;
     SslIoHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
   begin
     if not FileExists(AFileName) then
     begin
       raise EInOutError.CreateFmt('File %s not found', [AFileName]);
     end;

     ShortFileName := ExtractFileName(AFileName);
     URL := API_URL+ShortFileName
       + '?oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=' + FAppKey
       + '&oauth_token=' + FOAuth.AccessToken
       + '&oauth_signature=' + FAppSecret + '%26' + FOAuth.AccessTokenSecret;

     https := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
     Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
     try
       SslIoHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(https);
       SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
       SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;

       https.IOHandler := SslIoHandler;
       Stream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);

       https.Post(URL, Stream);
     finally
       FreeAndNil(Stream);
       FreeAndNil(https);
     end;
   end;
   ```